# `assert 1,2 == (2,3)` does not raise an AssertionError in python3

Tags: python, testing, assertion

As mentioned in the title

I expect

```py
assert 1,2 == (2,3)
```

to raise an `AssertionError` but it does not.

neither does

```py
assert 1,2 == 2
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because `assert` takes an argument after a comma...

Comment: so its evaluated as `assert 1, (2 == 2)` and if the first argument is falsy, then the assertion error will print the output of  `2 == 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assert syntax will check what comes before the comma, what comes next is what is printed in case the assertion is `False`.

Try it:

```
>>> assert 0,2 == (2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: False
```

You need to do `assert (1, 2) == (2, 3), "Assertion failure !"`

Answer (score 1):

This gets parsed as `assert 1` and `1 == (2,3)` as a separate argument.

`assert 1` is the same as `assert True`

You can see this by trying

`assert 0,1 == (0,1)` Which does raise.

Answer (score 1):

To be going more into details

```
def func():
    assert 1,2 == (2,3)
```

This is the `dis.dis` output of the above function:

```
          0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
          2 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        16
          4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (AssertionError)
          6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
          8 LOAD_CONST               4 ((2, 3))
         10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
         12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         14 RAISE_VARARGS            1
    >>   16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         18 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` jumps to 16 which completely skips `AssertionError`. And since the top of the stack is `1`, it `JUMP`s.